# The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, soap, wsdl

**When i try to call the Web service with username and password in authentication it gives me 401 (authentication error ) where as same is working with Soap UI.
My sample code and web.config is for reference  is for reference In Soap UI i am passing password and username in properties . **

```
ExternalTransferInRequest requestbody = new ExternalTransferInRequest();
    requestbody.referenceTxnId = 123456789101112131;
    requestbody.userName = "5F4aS7QIfS32A4qlCP0BlaEX4qi+lV0p";
    requestbody.password = "1kZ+ZKKNe6zRqot9Qels1g==";
    requestbody.deviceType = 9;
    requestbody.amount = "5000";
    requestbody.mobileAccountNumber = "33319015910";
    requestbody.bankName = "00–Ubank";
    requestbody.bankAccountNumber = "051000207960141";
    ExternalTransferInRequest1 request = new ExternalTransferInRequest1();
    ExternalTransferInResponse resposebody = new ExternalTransferInResponse();
    ExternalTransferInResponse1 response = new ExternalTransferInResponse1();
    //Customer_PortClient proxy = new Customer_PortClient();
    ThirdPartyServicesMiddleWareSoapPortClient c = new ThirdPartyServicesMiddleWareSoapPortClient();
    ThirdPartyServicesMiddleWareSoapPort ts = c;
    c.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "*************";
    c.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "********";
    //c.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "smw.tp_services_pibas";
    //c.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "Sybase@365";

    response = ts.ExternalTransferIn(request);
    resposebody = response.ExternalTransferInResponse;
```

Web.config

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="ThirdPartyServicesMiddleWareSoapPortSoap11" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
      textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
      messageEncoding="Text">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://**********:8083/mobiliser/thirdpartymw"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ThirdPartyServicesMiddleWareSoapPortSoap11"
    contract="TransferInSAP.ThirdPartyServicesMiddleWareSoapPort"
    name="ThirdPartyServicesMiddleWareSoapPortSoap11" />
</client>
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by using below web.config configuration

```
  <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="None" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
```